# PHP BCrypt for Ruby on Rails Devise passwords

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I am trying to verify with PHP some passwords generated by Devise Ruby on Rails.
Devise was configured to use bcrypt.

My code is:

```
$database_record = "$2a$10$..."; // generated by devise
$user_input = 'asdasd';
$password = crypt($user_input, '$2a$10$usesomesillystringforsalt$');

if (crypt($user_input, $database_record) == $password) {
    echo "<br/>Password verified!";
}
else {
    echo '<br/>failed!'; }
```

The documentation that I saw are using this method, but it doesn't work for me. Am I forgetting something?
The "pepper string" should be used in any way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused about this part.

```
$password = crypt($user_input, '$2a$10$usesomesillystringforsalt$');
```

I think you got confused by a later part of the documentation specifying how to create a hash and guarantee that it's bcrypt. In your case, you're verifying a hash so it will automatically do that.

What you want to do is skip that and do:

```
if (crypt($user_input, $database_record) == $database_record) {
```

So if this works how I'd expect it to, `crypt($user_input, $database_record)` will take the salt from `$database_record` and use it to run bcrypt on `$user_input`. Then you want to compare the result to `$database_record` again since it's the bcrypt hash of the correct password.

Comment: Hello Brendan! Thanks for your answer. What you say makes sense. But I tried it and still have the same problem... I think maybe I'm missing some extra encoding of Devise.

Comment: I finally discovered how to fix this. Your solution was correct, I needed only to unite the password and pepper and perform the encryption of both. Thanks again!

Comment: @Andrés When someone's answer is helpful, you can mark the up arrow next to their answer to mark that. If an answer solved your problem, you can click the checkbox. This helps other people who might have similar problems (because the best answers are at the top of the page) and helps the site by rewarding the people who helped you.

Comment: Hi Brendan, thanks again. I would like to mark as positive your answer, but I only have 11 points of reputation and I understand that I can't score until I have 15. When I reach them I will point you as you deserve :)

Comment: @Andrés Since you asked the question, you can always mark an answer as correct (the check mark).

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP 5 >= 5.5.0

```
$pepper = 'xxxyyyzzz'; //get value from config/initializers/devise.rb
$password = '12345678'; //clear password to validate

$db_pass = '***************************'; //password stored on database

$options = [
    'salt' => substr($db_pass,7)
];

$ok = ($db_pass == password_hash($password.$pepper, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options));
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally discovered how to fix this. Devise adds the pepper at the end of the password and then performs the crypt.

The working code is:

```
if (crypt($passwordToValidate.$pepper, $encryptedPassword) == $encryptedPassword)
   echo 'ok!';
else
   echo 'failed!';
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem in the fact that the php generated key like $2y ......., but ruby $2a ..... 
more here https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/issues/49